# What is this tree or large shrub with pink flowers like snapdragons?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

This tree or large shrub in our front garden in Shropshire (UK) has just come into flower, a couple of weeks ahead of last year (our first spring here). The picture was taken on 2nd May 2019.

[image: Pink tree/shrub main view]

I'm not sure if it's a tree or shrub as there are several main branches going almost right to the ground:

[image: Main stems/branches]

The tiny pink flowers are like little snapdragon flowers

[image: Pink snapdragon-like flowers]

and the almost round leaves are a lovely yellow/orange/pink colour. They are about 3cm (1.25in) approx. diameter and there are not many out yet.

[image: Leaves]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Cercis siliquastrum, commonly known as the Judas tree in the UK. Cercis canadansis is the other possibility, but C. siliquastrum is  not only more common here, but your useful image of the leaves confirms it as that variety. This tree flowers on bare wood, with the leaves arriving shortly afterwards; it'll be earlier in flower this year because last spring was much later and colder than this year's. Yours is a very nice, shapely specimen - can be described as a tree, but often has multiple trunks and may also be described as a shrub. Further info and images here https://www.burncoose.co.uk/site/plants.cfm?pl_id=1007

Comment: Or known as Redbud in the states; there is a variant , the Mexican redbud  found in southern TX.  Legume family and the flowers taste rather like green peas. It can be almost invasive with good conditions.

Comment: Your 'mexican redbud' is actually Cercis canadensis...

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Very helpful.